# onEdit(e) less than 30s trigger problem require help to shorten code to make it more efficient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem where my trigger onEdit() stopped after 30seconds and i need to keep re-pasting to trigger it again. Can you take a look and guide me on how to shorten it to make it work? I saw a person writing about it on this forum link: [Google sheets script, timed out just after 30ish something seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834195/google-sheets-script-timed-out-just-after-30ish-something-seconds/67087852#67087852) but i was not able to relate to it. Can anybody help me? Much appreciated as i am very new to this.

My code is as per below:

```
function onEdit(e){

//Variables

var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();

var IBDataEntry = "IB";
var IBDataSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(IBDataEntry); 
var IBlastRow = IBDataSheet.getLastRow();

var InboundPO = "Inbound POs";
var InboundPOSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(InboundPO);
var InboundlastRow = InboundPOSheet.getLastRow();
var searchRange = InboundPOSheet.getRange(2,2,InboundlastRow,1);
var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

var IBDataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IB"); 

 //Data Entry for Date Of Approval

if(col === 22 && row > 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === IBDataEntry){

var POList3 = IBDataSheet.getRange("V3:V").getValues();
var LastRow3 =   POList3.filter(String).length + 2;
var Entries3 = LastRow3 - row + 1;

for (var x = 0; x < Entries3 ; x++){
var ApprovalPO = IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 22).getValue();  
var ApprovalDate = IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 23).getValue(); 

if (IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 23).getValue() != '')  
for(var j=1;j<=InboundlastRow;j++){
if(rangeValues[j] == ApprovalPO){
InboundPOSheet.getRange(j+2,11).setValue(ApprovalDate);  
}
 }
 }
 } SummarySheet.getRange(36,3).setValue(currentDate);

//Data Entry for Date Of Arranging

if(col === 22 && row > 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === IBDataEntry){

var POList4 = IBDataSheet.getRange("V3:V").getValues();
var LastRow4 =   POList4.filter(String).length + 2;
var Entries4 = LastRow4 - row + 1;

for (var x = 0; x < Entries4 ; x++){
var ArrangingPO = IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 22).getValue();  
var ArrangingDate = IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 24).getValue(); 

if (IBDataSheet.getRange(row + x, 24).getValue() != '')    
for(var j=1;j<=InboundlastRow;j++){
if(rangeValues[j] == ArrangingPO){
InboundPOSheet.getRange(j+2,12).setValue(ArrangingDate);  
 }
 }
 }
 } SummarySheet.getRange(36,3).setValue(currentDate);
 }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to minimize calling `getValue()` and `setValue()` inside loops. It's much preferrable to get all data via `getValues()`, modify the resulting 2D array according to your purposes, and write the resulting data via `setValues()` (see [use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)). Also, you can avoid the 30 seconds limit if you [install the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of having a simple one.

Comment: Also, there are several `if` in your code that don't initiate a code block, be careful with this. Finally, can you provide more information on what this script is supposed to accomplish? What is the current data and what is the desired outcome? Maybe a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clarifying this, or at least some screenshots, could be useful for understanding your situation.

Comment: You should avoid using ranges like `this: IBDataSheet.getRange("V3:V").getValues()` because they tend to generate nulls between last row and max rows.

Comment: hi @lamblichus 

I am working on editing a macro that involves vlookup copy/paste data from Worksheet IB to Worksheet B Inbound POs. I would like to upload SS of my working file but seems to not work, so sorry. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hello @Cooper, can you suggest a more efficient way to define it? Thank you so much! I am very new to it.

Comment: I don't mean this as an analysis or review or a criticism of your code.  You can write codehowever you wish.  But I don't like it and I don't want to read it, so therefore I'm not going to read it.  I think you could benefit from learning more about the event object and using less unnecessary functions in your code.  I also suspect your trying to do to much in an onEdit().  Good luck.